# Getting an error when throwing a custom exception from a property

Tags: c#, properties, inner-classes, access-modifiers, custom-exceptions

Within a NeuralNetwork class, I've defined the nested class

```
public class TrainSetCardinalityMismatch : ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

This is to be thrown when a user tries to provide a training set that does not have the same number of elements as the answer set, or vice-versa. So in the setter for the training set, I check to see if the number of elements matches the number of elements in the answer set, and if not, I put

```
throw new TrainSetCardinalityMismatch();
```

but it's giving me the error

> NeuralNetwork.TrainSetCardinalityMismatch.TrainSetCardinalityMismatch()' is inaccessible due to its protection level

The trainingSet is also a field of the neuralnetwork class (which shouldn't matter since the error is public anyway), and  don't think the ArgumentOutOfRangeException is private.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: How about your NeuralNetwork? I think it must be public in order to throw nested exception as compiler cannot know where it will be handled.

Answer (score 0):

ignore this question - I forgot to put an access modifier on the constructor...

Comment: If you think your mistake would help somebody in future pls update your answer and add some code and explain completely. Otherwise, delete the question. Thanks